# How to use component not directly exported?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to use a component not been directly exported, as below:
in library folder `TopComponent/index.js`, it is:

```
import NeededModule from "./NeededModule";
import TopComponent from "./presenters/TopComponent";

TopComponent.NeededModule = NeededModule ;

export default TopComponent; // the library only export this
```

in my code, I can only import the TopComponent. with the code below:

```
//my code
import TopComponent from '@lib/topcomponent';
...
render () {
    return ( <TopComponent.NeededModule /> )
}
```

will get error

> Cannot read property 'NeededModule ' of undefined

how can I use that component? checked during debug, in the webpack generated file, in the render function, it contains a line
`return _React2.default.createElement(_topComponent.TopComponent.NeededModule,...` with the `TopComponent` is undefined.
If I modify the js file generated by webpack, change the line to `return _React2.default.createElement(_topComponent.default.NeededModule,...` it will work..

Comment: Which line causes the error? And where do you declare `TopComponent`?

Comment: Yes, it's undefined. You need to import the TopComponent before you use `TopComponent.NeededModule=NeededModule`

Comment: you need to first define the component , may be with const .
it seems to be an object so 
const TopComponent = {NeededModule}

Comment: @BhojendraNepal TopComponent is defined in another js file in the library, just updated.

Comment: can you show us TopComponent?

Comment: TopComponent is just a normal Component, `import React, { Component } from "react";
export default class TopComponent extends Component { ...`

Comment: If I modify the js file generated by webpack, to `_topComponent.default.NeededModule`, it will work...

Answer (score 0):

Have you try

```
// in TopComponent/index.js
export { default as NeededModule } from './NeededModule';
export { default as TopComponent } from './TopComponent';

// in your code
import { TopComponent, NeededModule } from '@lib/topcomponent';
```

I know it is not really what you are trying to do but i think it'll help.

Comment: thanks, if the library export the NeededModule directly it should work. I don't want to modify the library, is there a way to use NeededModule with only  `TopComponent.NeededModule = NeededModule;`  in TopComponent/index.js?

Comment: Have you try to update the prototype? Like `TopComponent.prototype.NeededModule = NeededModule;`